# How Can I Read Video Using SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 kit

Tags: image, video, embedded-linux, video-processing, atmel

I want to take frame from video and display it.
I can crop frame using Gstreamer package.
But I need to know how can I read video using `SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 Device`.
I want to Read Video using HDMI input.

Below are Gstreamer package commands

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=0 ! fakesink

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=18 ! imxg2dvideosink framebuffer=/dev/fb0
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Question is nothing to do with Yocto. Use only relevant tags!

Comment: *"I want to Read Video using HDMI input"* -- That board does not have any *"HDMI input"*.  What device do you plan on connecting in order to *"read video"*?

Comment: @sawdust i am reading video using ISC interface.

Comment: Study the Linux4SAM page on the ISC, https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/UsingISC, which has GStreamer 0.10 and 1.0 examples.

Comment: @sawdust thank you. i visited that page.but can you suggest me how can i interface camera to the board.it is 30 pin ISC.which extender should i use to connect camera